# Error when I delete a user: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to delete a user inside my application, when I click the button that calls the delete function I'm getting this wrong,
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined.
but when I update the page the user is deleted.
[image]

```
export const deleteUser = (clientId, userId, token) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/user/${clientId}/${userId}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

const destroy = clientId => {
        deleteUser(clientId, user._id, token).then(data => {
            if(data.error) {
                console.error(data.error);
            }else{
                loadUser();
            }
        })
    }

<button onClick={()=> destroy(person._id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Deletar</button>
```

//Node my backend.

```
exports.remove = (req, res) =>{
 
    User
    .findByIdAndRemove(req.params.clientId)
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
        if(!doc) { return res.status(404).end();}
        return res.status(204).end();
    }) 
    .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

Comment: Post your backend code called through the api endpoint for delete

Comment: When you use `return` inside `then` block it'll return data to the callback. if you want to return data to your `deleteUser` method, try declaring a variable above, asign the value in `then` block and return it after the process.

Comment: Yeah I´ll do it